# I want to import data grid in SQL Server, but I don't want to duplicate data

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

What is the correct syntax to use if I have a lot of data (100000+ rows) and I don't want to duplicate data when I add more data into the table?

This is how my insert data button looks like:

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constring = @"DELETED FOR SECURITY REASONS";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dgvEmployees.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            var str = @"INSERT INTO USERSTable  VALUES ('" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Issuer"].Value + "', '" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Customer"].Value + "'," + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Card"].Value + ",'" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["License plate No"].Value + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Transactiondate"].Value + "', '" +                   dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Product description (com.)"].Value + "', '" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Quantity"].Value + "', '" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Gross CC"].Value + "', '" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["VAT1"].Value + "', '" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Voucher"].Value + "', '" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Mileage"].Value + "', '" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Additional info"].Value + "', '" +                   dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Supply country"].Value + "', '" +                   dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Site Town"].Value + "', '" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Product DEL"].Value + "', '" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Unitprice"].Value + "', '" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Amount"].Value + "', '" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Discount"].Value + "', '" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Surcharge"].Value + "', '" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["VAT"].Value + "', '" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Suppliercurrency"].Value + "', '" +                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Invoice No"].Value + "', '" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Invoice date"].Value + "', '" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Invoiced?"].Value + "', '" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Vat2010"].Value + "', '" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["State"].Value + "', '" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Supplier"].Value + "', '" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Cost 1"].Value + "', '" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Cost 2"].Value + "', '" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Reference No"].Value + "', '" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Recordtype"].Value + "', '" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Amount other"].Value + "', '" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Is listprice ?"].Value + "', '" +                   dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Date to"].Value + "', '" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["Final Trx."].Value + "', '" + 
                dgvEmployees.Rows[i].Cells["LPI"].Value + "', '" + "');";

           try
           {
               using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(str, con))
               {
                   con.Open();
                   com.ExecuteNonQuery();
               }
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
           }

           con.Close();
       }

       MessageBox.Show("Records uploaded.");
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated...

Thank you...

Comment: Your question is just unreadable...

Comment: handle it in database side. Add a unique constraint

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **NEVER EVER** concatenate together your SQL statements like this; **ALWAYS** use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: I know I should never do this, but my boss asked this from me specifically so I had no choice but to concatenate everything like this.

Comment: Completely not what you asked, but why are you opening and closing that connection for each row?  You might want to just open it, do your updates and then close it.

Answer (score 0):

If you choise to solve it on database side, just add unique constraint to a unique row as apomene mentioned in his comment.

For software side there are too much solutions like using [DataTable.GetChanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2552649(v=vs.110).aspx) to get added and edited rows or (if you just let users to **add** rows not edit) you can keep the old row count then use it in your for statement like:

```
for (int i = oldRowsCount-1; i < dgvEmployees.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
```

**EDIT**: For security reasons (and also it's easier) I strongly reccomend you **not** to use String.Format method for your queries, use [SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx).

Edit2: Thanks for commenting Patrick i missed "not" word.

Comment: *I strongly reccomend you to use String.Format method for your queries* > I hope you mean **NOT** to use `string.Format`.